# In MySQL, is it more efficient to run my calculation everytime I query the database, or save the values in a new table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a 2-D table of values that I am running through an algorithm to filter out the zero values from the front columns and back columns, and then taking the average across the rows.

In addition to doing this, I am sorting the averages by another column's values.

So in the end, I need a 2xN table with ordered values in my first column and the averages in the 2nd column after filtering out the zero values.

Is the best implementation for this running a routine every query? Or would it be okay for my to run through these computations and then create an entirely new organized table of these values with a foreign key to link it to the other?

Comment: How often does the information (and therefore the calculation) change, and how often do you need to refer to it?

Comment: Whether or not you cache the results depends on a whole host of requirements and system issues that are not described in your question.

Comment: Performance depends on the schema, storage engine, indexes, volume of rows, query plan, and more.

Comment: @lurker the information never changes once it is input into the database.

Comment: @reannb the volume of rows will be very large (~100,000+)

Comment: Right, but does new information get *added* on some regular bases and therefore affect the calculations you want to collect each time? That will dictate what approach is efficient. If your calculations change little, then a separate table. Otherwise, not.  Or depending upon the calculations, sometimes you can do a delta calculation based upon only the new information that comes in, when it does. A lot of variables here, so one cannot answer your question without knowing a lot more about your scenario/requirements.

Comment: @lurker Everytime I create my 2-D table, I have to run these calculations, so yes it gets added on a regular basis.